# XSLT parameter is always empty <xsl:param name="mediaFolderId" select="/macro/mediaFolderId" />

Tags: xslt, umbraco

I created an xslt called GraphicsRowSlider with the following parameters

```
<xsl:param name="mediaFolderId" select="/macro/mediaFolderId" />
<xsl:param name="title" select="/macro/title" />
```

And added the parameters title and mediaFolderId to the related macro.

I then created new Macro Container data type and selected the macro GraphicsRowSlider as allowed macro. I then added a new field of the new data type into a document type and then imported that field into a template.

Finally, from the content, I inserted the macro and added a title and selected media folder... However, I could see that the macro calls the correct xslt with the correct title and mediaFolderId but the parameters are always empty!

Any thought?! Note, I always get this

```
<?UMBRACO_MACRO macroalias="GraphicsRowSlider" title="Add Title here" mediaFolderId="1159" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax you are using suggests that you are using an old umbraco version, which one are you using?

The definition how to work with macro parameters can be found on the umbraco wiki: http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/templates/umbracomacro-element/macro-parameters

hth

Comment: I am using umbraco 4.7.1 but couldn't find any new information on how to use Macro and parameters, so, I used the videos on Umbraco TV, which obviously out of date. Anyway, thanks for you guys and I will check the link @thoehler sent here, hope it is for umbraco 4.5+, isn't it?

Comment: It's all the same for all 4.x versions, so it's supported in 4.5+

Answer (score 0):

Your input is an attribute (at least your xml example suggests this) so your xpath should look like this:

```
<xsl:param name="mediaFolderId" select="/macro/@mediaFolderId" />
<xsl:param name="title" select="/macro/@title" />
```